# Canadian NRI aunty shares her living experience with her niece and nephews

Tags: identification-request

I remember reading this story in my Indian primary school curriculum and it had some impact on my thinking. It's about an [NRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-resident_Indian_and_person_of_Indian_origin) aunt coming to India to visit her niece and nephews while they are curiously waiting for her.

**Plot:** The kids start criticizing India on a random basis and become more biased, bickering, praising Canada, and showing signs of envy. The aunt calmly listens to them and tries to discuss it from every angle.

She shares how vibrant and unique Indian weather and cultures are and how Canada is always cold. She talks about diversifying culture, languages, food, and a variety of things to do in India, and the kids start changing their minds.

Then one of the kids curiously asks, "Then why are you even living in Canada and not India".

I forgot her answer and wanted to know that. I guess her answer was more of a balancing act of the story. Like every place has its pros and cons.

It might be from the early 90s, I read it during 1995-2000 in either the English or maybe Hindi textbook of the CBSE board curriculum. I was in Delhi government school but that fact doesn't matter as the CBSE board has the same books all over India as per my knowledge.

**Language:** I guess English but it can be Hindi.

No idea if the writer was a male, female, part of the story themselves or a mere spectator. I don't remember if there was a narrator or not but there were dialogue exchanges between the Aunt and kids (there were multiple kids, I will bet more than 2). I think the kids' age was not addressed or I forgot but it gives the young vibe.

Funny side note I did end up in Canada myself so relatability kind of increasing my curiosity.